# Adding a customised Email to VBA

Tags: vba

I am currently developing a database in Access and using VBA code. 
We have been asked to create a customized email using VBA which must end in @Students.src.ac.uk
I have attached the images of my code. Every time I try to load it, it shows "object required"
Any help would be greatly appriciated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTvht.png)

Answer (score 0):

First - and your program isn't complaining about this *yet* - but you should concatenate Strings with `&`, not `+`.  Second, an email address needs an `"@"` symbol somewhere in it.

Your main issue is `Students.src.ac.uk` - Access is looking for an **Object** called `Students`, which has Property `src`, which has Property `ac`, which has property or method `uk`

[Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/string-data-type) go in **quotes**:

```
SomeText = Hello World 'This will throw an error
OtherText = "Hello World" ' This will work
```

So, apply all of that to fill out the [`Caption` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.label.caption) of your `lbl_email` Label:

```
lbl_email.Caption = Left([first_name], 3) & Left([Last_name], 3) & "@students.src.ac.uk"
```

Comment: I have tried the code you have given me and it throws an error saying "Method or Data member not found"

Comment: Hmm...  Try removing the `.Caption` - I had been assuming that `lbl_email` was a Label, but I can't see your actual Form.  You can also use `MsgBox Left([first_name], 3) & Left([Last_name], 3) & "@students.src.ac.uk"` as a debug, to check that your string is correct/valid (I have my doubts about whether `[first_name]` and `[Last_name]` will give return the values that you want)

Comment: All i am looking to do is use the first name and last name to create an email with "@"Students.src.ac.uk at the end using the first letter of the first name and the entire last name. I need to use the form to populate the database in Access

Comment: Furthermore it is a textbox that I am using but it has been disabled, the email must be automatically created by merging the first and last name together when they have filled out the form would you like me to send you a screenshot of the form and the code as I am really struggling to see what's happening. I tried using.Value and.Text but neither of them made any difference, when I loaded up the datavase, the email section was still empty.